# how to have a bit of obliqueness when passing data to AWS API Gateway?

Tags: ios, aws-api-gateway

I have an iOS app that takes data "profile" from a server, and send it to API Gateway along with one other value "appKnowsThisKey".

I'd like the iOS app to remain agnostic to the structure of "profile".

I've created a Model on API Gateway which does know the keys of the dictionary.

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "ExampleModel",
"type": "object", "properties": {
    "appKnowsThisKey" : {"type": "string" },
    "profile": { 
        "type": "object", "properties": {
            "key1": {"type": "string" },
            "key2": {"type": "string" },
            "key3": {
                "type": "array", "items": {"type": "string" }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

API Gateway Deployment to iOS has created Swift classes: `ExampleModel` and `ExampleModel_profile`

I have an object `profile` in the iOS app holding the values in a `[String:AnyObject]`.

How can I assign the dictionary in my iOS to the API Gateway Model for profile? e.g., Do I redefine "profile" in ExampleModel to be a `string` and pass in a JSON string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the iOS app agnostic to the structure of "profile", the only way would be to define "profile" in ExampleModel as string and pass a JSON string.

When the structure changes in the future, you can use Integration Request mapping template to map the JSON into however the endpoint expects it to be.

```
{
    "someNewField" : "$input.json('$.profile.someOldField')"
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I agree that this is the best solution. APIG adds some nice sugar.